# How to change color of a jQuery Validate Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the [jQuery Validate Popover plugin](https://github.com/mingliangfeng/jquery.validate.bootstrap.popover) and it works perfect...except that the popovers appears on white color, instead of the soft red color it appers on the plugin's demo page.

I have been try to style them using CSS, and I was able to change the popup color, but not the arrow:

```
.error-popover  {
    background-color: red;  <-- this works
    color:  white;
}

.error-popover .arrow:after {
    border-color: red transparent;   <-- this doesn't
}
```

You can check what I'am trying [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vespina/Xuu3K/2/)

I am using the latest version of Bootstrap3, jQuery and jQuery Validate.  Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Thanks

Victor Espina

Answer (score 0):

this css style seems to do the trick!

```
.popover.right > .arrow:after {
    border-right-color:red;
}
```

see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xuu3K/3/) on jsfiddle.

Comment: Yep, it's just the specificity of the selector that was causing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the additional css attributes.

EG: `.popover.right>.arrow`, and `.popover.right>.arrow:after`

Adjusted code: http://jsfiddle.net/Xuu3K/4/

```
.error-popover .arrow:after {
    /*border-color: red transparent;*/
}

.error-popover.right>.arrow:after {
    border-right-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
added added

```
 .popover.right > .arrow:after{ border-right-color:red;
}
```

see working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/Xuu3K/5/

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap tooltip: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips and on email's `focusout` function validate the entry, if that failed then call the bootstrap tooltip to display the error

http://jsfiddle.net/Xuu3K/11/

Make sure you correctly import the jquery and bootstrap javascripts, otherwise they might conflict or not work.

**--update--**

I made more changes to customize the `tooltip`

just change following CSSs to whatever you like:

```
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 500px;
    background-color: #E4F1FF;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top-color: #E4F1FF;
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.tooltip-arrow {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tooltip.in {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: useful information but this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia In the demo, when you `focusout` the email textbox, you've got the message right away, while in his code you don't.
Some other people fixed his issue (CSS issue). I addressed the `focousout` part

Comment: add the css resolve to your answer and you'll have the best one!

Comment: @JacobRaccuia I made the changes.